# How do I mark a pushpoint with radial gradient?

Tags: bing-maps, bing

My website uses a pushpoint generator in js the following way

```
function plotPoint(cord){
  var point = new window.Microsoft.Maps.Location(cord[0], cord[1]);

  //Create custom Pushpin
  var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(point, {
    icon: createPoint(100,100,100,5)
  });

  map.entities.push(pin);
}
```

Further, using the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/pushpins/custom-canvas-pushpin-example),

```
function createPoint(r, g, b, radius) {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width = 24;
  c.height = 24;

  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';

  //Draw a path in the shape of an arrow.
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(12, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(5, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(12, 15);
  ctx.lineTo(19, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(12, 0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  //Generate the base64 image URL from the canvas.
  return c.toDataURL();
}
```

The pushpoint is created.
[image]

However, when I try creating my own graphic by

```
function createPoint(r, g, b, radius){
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width = radius*2;
  c.height = radius*2;

  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  console.log(ctx.toDataURL());
  // Create gradient
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(radius,radius,0,radius,radius,radius);
  grd.addColorStop(0,'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');
  grd.addColorStop(1,"white");

  // Fill with gradient
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  console.log(ctx)
  return ctx.toDataURL(); 
}
```

Which should give something like [image] but simply does not create a pushpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code block you are only passing in three parameters, not a radius parameter. Double check your code to ensure you are passing in a radius or add a default radius value to the `createPoint` function.

**Update**

Ok, here are the issues:

- `toDataUri` is only available on the canvas, not the context.
- You are not drawing the gradient, only setting it as the fill style.

Here is the modified code:

```
function createPoint(r, g, b, radius){
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = radius*2;
    c.height = radius*2;

    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    // Create gradient
    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(radius,radius,0,radius,radius,radius);
    grd.addColorStop(0,'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');
    grd.addColorStop(1,"white");

    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle =grd;
    ctx.fill();

    return c.toDataURL(); 
}
```

Comment: My bad, that was a question draft typo. Can you check now?